# Как получить текущий тег <Script> без document.currentScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Собственно суть вопроса понятна из названия. Например есть файл `script.js` подключенный в `HTML` в виде с атрибутом:  `<script src="script.js" attr1="1">` и в начале его выполнения нужно получить конкретно этот элемент, что бы получить значение атрибута. Вроде есть `document.currentScript`, но он ещё не воспринимается некоторыми браузерами. Есть ли какая-нибудь реализация поддерживаемая всеми браузерами и минимум от 10 IE? Желательно без Jquery, но можно и с ним.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Использование `document.currentScript`

```
<script>
var me = document.currentScript;
</script>
```

Проблемы:

- не работает в IE и старых браузерах

### 2. Последний выполненный скрипт

```
<script>
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
var me = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
</script>
```

Проблемы:

- не работает с динамически добавленными скриптами
- не работает с асинхронными скриптами(`defer` и `async`)

### 3. Брать по src

```
<script src="//my_site.com/script.js"></script>
```

В script.js:

```
var me = document.querySelector('script[src*="script.js"]');
```

Проблемы:

- необходимость правки в скрипте при изменении его названия
- разница между продакшеном и dev-средой

### 4. Брать по id

```
<script id="scriptID">
var me = document.getElementById('scriptID');
</script>
```

Проблемы:

- необходимость уникального названия
- добавление дополнительного атрибута

**Итог:** как видно - нет универсального метода. Но в вашем случае методы 1,2(возможно),3 - не подходят.

потому оптимальным будет *метод 4*. (он определенно лучше метода с `src`)

Comment: Думаю в моем данном случае я все-же остановлюсь на третьем варианте. Второй не подойдет, так как мне необходимо в основном скрипте добавлять другие скрипты(гугл+Яндекс счетчики). А атрибут id используется для ид метрик в добавляемых скриптах. В любом случае спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var script = document.querySelector('script[src*="jquery.min.js"]');
console.log(script.getAttribute('attr1'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" attr1="1"></script>
```

Comment: Мне кажется искать по фиксированному имени не лучший вариант. К тому же при использовании `querySelector`, если на странице 2 одинаковых скрипта подключаются, допустим, один вначале, а второй в конце, то оба выдадут атрибут первого скрипта. Или я не прав?

Comment: @BwehaaFox а каков смысл подключать один и тот же код дважды? если же всё таки есть в планах такое, то можно брать атрибут последнего скрипта. 

поиск осуществляется по названию подключенного файла, что в 99.99% не подключаются дважды. 

про фиксированность: так часто будет меняться название файла скрипта?

Comment: 2 одинаковых скрипта я привел как пример. По поводу фиксированности: допустим я буду использовать такой поиск в нескольких разных скриптах на странице, и не хотелось бы при изменении адреса или имени скрипта, лезть менять его ещё и в сам скрипт. Суть вопроса была в том что бы найти текущий скрипт а не конкретный.

Comment: Если и использовать данный вариант, то всё же удобнее использовать не на столько жёсткий селектор: `'script[src$="jquery.min.js"]'` или `'script[src*="jquery.min.js"]'`

Comment: а в каких браузерах не поддерживается currentScript? IE<8?

Comment: IE(5.5%), Opera Mini(5%), UC Browser(7%) не поддерживаются полностью. Покрайне мере по данным [этого](http://caniuse.com/#feat=document-currentscript) сайта

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю что решение для не асинхронных скриптов такое:

```
var s =  document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var attr = s[s.length-1].getAttribute("attr1");
```

Данный способ корректен, только если скрипт изначально в `HTML`. Если вставить через скрипт в `HTML`,то работать будет не корректно. Возможно есть более универсальный способ.